# Find the perfect square in the string

Tags: c++, python, algorithm

A perfect square is taken in binary and some bits are replaced with "?" for example 1??, the number would be 4.(or 1????000???0000)

I need to find that perfect square.(there will be only such possible number)

number of '?'s in the string be n

To find that number what I am doing is iterating through 2**n numbers(111,110,101,100) and checking if it is a perfect square. I am using following function to check if it is a perfect square.

```
bool issqr(int n){
   int d=(int)(sqrt(n));
   if(d*d==n) return true;
   else return false;
}
```

Even though in python I did it, it is taking a lot of time, so I shifted to C++ using only bit operations for populating 2**n numbers(which was much faster than the python version)

but this fails if the number has more than 64 bits

How to avoid this problem? How can I do the same thing if a number has say 120 bits.

(10100110???1?1?01?1?011000?1100?00101000?1?11001101100110001010111?0?1??0110?110?01?1100?1?0110?1?10111?01?0111000?10??101?01)

Comment: Are all but the highest bit replaced by '?' or could there be a more complex pattern such as `1??1??1` ?

Comment: Please add a 120 bit example

Comment: These kind of problems are formulated so that brute force is unreasonable. They require mathematical simplification, and algorithmic insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than re-writing in C++ you should first have looked at improving your algorithm. The lowest possible answer is the square root from the original value with all '?' replace by 0 rounded up, the highest possible answer is the square root of the pattern with the '?'s replaced by 1 rounded down. Find those two values, iterate through them, square and check against the pattern.

This is faster both because you are iterating through many fewer numbers and because you aren't calculating any square roots in the loop: squaring is much easier.

You don't need to compare string to check for a match:

```
mask = int(pattern.replace('0', '1').replace('?', '0'), 2)
test = int(pattern.replace('?', '0'), 2)

def is_match(n):
    return (n&mask)==test
```

So putting it all together:

```
def int_sqrt(x):
    if x < 0:
        raise ValueError('square root not defined for negative numbers')
    n = int(x)
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    a, b = divmod(n.bit_length(), 2)
    x = 2**(a+b)
    while True:
        y = (x + n//x)//2
        if y >= x:
            return x
        x = y

def find_match(pattern):
    lowest = int(pattern.replace('?', '0'), 2)
    highest = int(pattern.replace('?', '1'), 2)
    mask = int(pattern.replace('0', '1').replace('?', '0'), 2)
    lowsqrt = int_sqrt(lowest)
    if lowsqrt*lowsqrt != lowest:
            lowsqrt += 1
    highsqrt = int_sqrt(highest)
    for n in range(lowsqrt, highsqrt+1):
        if (n*n & mask)==lowest:
            return n*n

print(find_match('1??1??1'))
print(find_match('1??0??1'))
print(find_match('1??????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????1??0??1'))
```

Output:

```
121
81
151115727461209345152081
```

N.B. This only works in Python 3.x, the last test will overflow `range` in Python 2.x

Comment: If a number has 120 bits and say 70 "?" to check number has same pattern takes more time because I am dealing with strings here. Rather I preferred only numbers with same pattern.

Comment: If the number has 120 bits you'll have to write your own sqrt or use a big-number library.

Comment: If you have 120 bits and 70 "?" then any kind of search will take a long time.

Comment: @Duncan and I can't use bit-wise operations right? How to change the last two lines of your code?

Comment: Why can you not use bitwise operations? That seems a strange restriction

Comment: Can I use bit-wise operations if a number has more than 64 bits? because last time I tried using bit-shift operators it gave me an error.(Cannot convert into C lang)

Comment: If you are using Python then you can use bitwise operations on any length of integer. However `range` will probably break at the sort of numbers you are talking about if you use Python 2.x, so use Python 3.x

Comment: Yeah, got it. Yes it broke even if I used xrange.

Comment: Try my code with one of your 120bit values, I'd be interested in how it performs. With the 77bit test value output is effectively instant, but depending where the '?' value appear a 120 bit value could still be doing 2^59 iterations.

Comment: 10100110???1?1?01?1?011000?1100?00101000?1?11001101100110001010111?0?1??0110?110?01?1100?1?0110?1?10111?01?0111000?10??101?01

Comment: how much time it takes for this pattern?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24507/discussion-between-anil-and-duncan)

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding, given an integer `n` you are trying to find a square number `sq` that matches :

> 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 < sq < 2<sup>n+1</sup> - 1

This condition is the mathematic translation of "my number must have the form 1????" where there are `n` "?".

First, you can notice that if `n` is even, the number 2<sup>n</sup> is a perfect square and matches your condition (in binary, it is the number 1000...000 - n zeroes -).

If `n` is uneven (say n = 2.p + 1), then 2<sup>n+1</sup> is a perfect square ((2<sup>p+1</sup>)<sup>2</sup>). Computing the following number will give you a perfect square :

> (2<sup>p+1</sup> - 1)<sup>2</sup>

To satisfy the first inequality, p must satisfy :

> 2<sup>n</sup> - 1 < (2<sup>p+1</sup> - 1)<sup>2</sup>

Then

> 0 < 2<sup>n+1</sup> - 2<sup>p+2</sup> + 1 - 2<sup>n</sup> + 1,

Finally,

> 2<sup>n</sup> + 2 - 2<sup>p+2</sup> > 0
>   Or
>   2<sup>2p</sup> - 2<sup>p+1</sup> + 1 > 0

If we consider the function that matches p with f(p) such that :

> f(p) = 2<sup>2p</sup> - 2<sup>p+1</sup> + 1

This function is defined for each positive real number, and is strictly increasing. Moreover, f(0) = 0. Finally, the initial condition is satisfied when `p > 0` !
For `p = 0` - or `n = 1` -, the problem does not have a valid solution.

Comment: @Anil I posted the answer before you edited your question. The answer you accepted is the best bet you have

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate trough all the 2**n numbers to find the perfect square, in fact you only need one fractional square operation:

Say you have integer n and you want to find the largest perfect square smaller or equal than n, let's call it m.
Then:

```
d = (int)sqrt(n);
m = d*d;
```

Explanation:

Assume there is a perfect square m' larger than m , this implies there is an integer d' so that: d' > d and d'*d' = m'.

But d' >=d+1 and (d+1)*(d+1) > n so m' > n in contradiction to our requirement m' <= n.

Now to your question:

in order to find the perfect squares just change to "1" all of the "?" and find the perfect square if it conforms to your string you got the number you're looking for, if not change just enough "?" from the msb to "0" so that the resulting number is smaller or equal to the perfect square you just found, and keep going until you find the perfect square or run out of options.

Comment: It isn't clear in the question whether all but one bit is replaced by a question mark (in which case your answer is correct), or whether there could be a pattern such as `1??0??1` in which case it gets more complicated.

Comment: @Eli Algranti it is not that you will only one such number and that even then it may not have same bit pattern.

Comment: Sorry kept hit save before finishing the answer

Comment: @Eli and the problem is not with the algorithm but deal with 120 bit integers.

Comment: @Anil How where you coping with that on python? To do that you'll need to write your own big number library (not an easy task) or use an available one (such as http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Roots.html#Integer-Roots)

Comment: @Anil even (specially) with a big number factory you'll need to improve your algorithm if you want acceptable performance.

Answer (score -1):

Your operations may be returning something too large for an integer...
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/

Comment: Your answer is erroneous. Bitfield structures cannot exceed size of an int.